# createdurablesubscriber not receiving persistence messages activemq

Tags: android, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

My Reciever is not recieving persistance message.
If reciever is online and if I am sending message then it is recieving message but if I am not online (not connect to activeMQ) then I send message after sending message I connect to activeMQ. In this condition I am not getting message.
Here is my reciever code.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(Constants.USER_NAME,
            Constants.PASSWORD,Constants.BROKER_URL);
    connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);



        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.setClientID(Utility.getIMEINumber(context));
        connection.start();
        Topic destination = new ActiveMQTopic(Constants.TOPIC_NAME);

        Session receiverSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        receiverSession.createDurableSubscriber(destination,Utility.getIMEINumber(context));
        MessageConsumer receiver = receiverSession.createConsumer(destination);
```

My sender code is below

```
jmsTemplateTopic.convertAndSend(objectMessage);
```

the jms topic is configured with persistance delivery

Comment: Has the durable subscriber connected at least once before the messages were sent?

Comment: Yes. firstly I am connecting then disconnecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a durable subscriber, you should also use it ! In the code above, you are creating two subscribers, the first one durable, which you don't use, and the second one non-durable, which I guess you do use (can't tell since the rest of your code is missing).
So instead of:

```
    Session receiverSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    receiverSession.createDurableSubscriber(destination,Utility.getIMEINumber(context));
    MessageConsumer receiver = receiverSession.createConsumer(destination);
```

try:

```
    Session receiverSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageConsumer receiver = receiverSession.createDurableSubscriber(destination,Utility.getIMEINumber(context));
```